# GPG openvas9 debian

Tags: debian, gpg

Hay all i am trying to build an openvas docker container and haveing some issues with openvasmd.

I now have it 80% working, but stuck with something, that will cause me issues, when i try to add auto updating and so on.

i got three sessions open 
Session A: Where i ran all the commands to setup openvas
Session B: monitoring the openvasmd.log
Session C: Other things

If i run the command "openvasmd --rebuild" on "Session A" "Session B"  outputs "Updating NVT cache."

If i run the command "openvasmd --rebuild" on "Session C" "Session B" 
outputs "error starting search for OpenPGP key 'OpenVAS Credential Encryption': Inappropriate ioctl for device "

From what i can work out "session A" has openvas GPG setup to auth, but "session c" does not.

My question is, how do i get GPG info working on "session c" as well.

This has been driving me nuts all day and this is where i got to.

All / Nay help would be welcome and gratefull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it out :D

ASked the IRC chat and some on came back wiht the below link

https://lists.wald.intevation.org/pipermail/openvas-discuss/2017-January/010592.html

Turns out, to be an know bug in an lib file with debian